# AWS HTTP API Gateway connected to ALB returns 503

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

**My current solution:**
My application consists of two separate services/containers deployed to ECS. These services are inside Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) and to expose the application I created EC2 Application Load Balancer, which works flawlessly, I can access the application through Load Balancer URL easily.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
Currently I'm trying to create an API Gateway linked to the load balancer mentioned above, to access the application by API Gateway instead of Load Balancer.

**What I did to achieve this**
I found an AWS tutorial which basically does what I'm trying to do, so I went step by step [with this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-private-integration.html#http-api-private-integration-create-api)

1. Created Http API Gateway
2. Created VPC-LINK (connected to all possibles subnets and all possible security groups just in case)
3. Created single route `ANY /{proxy+}` to catch basically everything
4. Created integration to that route (where I selected mentioned above load balancer as a target service).

Everything is step by step, the same as in the tutorial, but unfortunately last step where I should see my webpage I see `ERROR: 503 {"message":"Service Unavailable"}`

**What I did additionally to solve the issue:**

- Added Api Gateway logs, but I'm not receiving anything interesting there, just raw data like below:

```
{
    "requestId": "PgELwjAyjoEEPgQ=",
    "ip": "185.244.96.51",
    "requestTime": "24/Mar/2022:18:09:40 +0000",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "routeKey": "ANY /{proxy+}",
    "status": "503",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "33"
}
```

- played with different load balancer listeners (443 or 80).
- played with different security groups (tried with same security groups as ALB, or with all possible security groups)

**The question is, what I'm missing here?**
I guess the problem lies somewhere in the connection between VPC link and load balancer, but to be honest I don't know how to check and verify it. I clicked everything step by step, in many places there was single choice option, so I'm really confused where I could have made a mistake. Here is an illustrative photo of the infrastructure and my guess where the problem could be (but it's still a guess.[image]

Comment: If the ALB is publicly accessible, you shouldn't need the VPC Link. I'd try removing that first to simplify things.

Comment: Thanks for response @jaredready . I believe that idea was to set APIGW public and later, when everything will work properly just hide ALB (make it private). That's why I feel like VPC is needed.

Comment: hi @degeath How you finally fix the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is, why? Like seriously, APIGW doesn't provide any additional value over the ALB. If you are already using an ALB, the easiest, cheapest, and best thing to do, is point your route53 DNS at the ALB and be done.

In any case VPC-link will never work, APIGW doesn't work with internal VPC, and VPC-link requires the client to be in the same VPC as the service. Since VPC-link is inside the VPC and the HTTP API is outside of course this would cause a problem, and specifically "I can't find that dependency" where 503 is the expected status code.

If some ridiculous reason you still wanted to use APIGW with a public ALB, you can point the APIGW directly at the ALB DNS, and be done. But again, this offers negative value AND costs additional money + performance for an all around negative impact on your users, developers, and your corporate wallet.

If for some reason after all that, here is the [AWS Documentation on VPC-Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-private-integration.html). In reality the problem with the setup is likely a further configuration issue. You can validate this by checking the ALB flow logs.

Comment: Well, I don't know exact reason, because the originator no longer works, but soon there will be third service (probably outside our VPN) and they wanted to use the same Authorizer for all those services, so maybe that's the reason why they decided for API Gateway. 

`to use APIGW with ALB, you can point the APIGW directly at the ALB DNS` - can you help me out how to do it?

Comment: Worth to mention that at the end ALB will be only `internal`.

Comment: @degath Did you find a solution for your issue?

Comment: @warren I guess APIGW provides more fine-grained security options

Comment: Yes but they are bad and don't really work. Looking at usage plans that don't scale and are brittle, default authorizers that don't allow configuration, policy checks that will never understand your code solution, openapi models that only support a far deprecated version of the OpenAPI specification, all of these are terrible. APIGW should only be used if you are using lambda to provide an Custom Domain. If Lambda came out tomorrow with custom domains, APIGW would no longer have any value.

Answer (score 3):

One reason to want to do this approach is that the API Gw is being used with say Cognito to provide the access security to the backend API in the VPC rather than say an x-api-key header which is very insecure.  In this way API Gw can provide user group level security of all the APIs exported by the backend service.  It can also be used to deny access to certain apis through route configuration.

Comment: Sorry that answer was meant to be a reply to "why would you want to do this".

To try and make up for that mistake, I have been fighting this issue as well and it turns out that you NEED TO MAKE SURE THE VPC LINK HAS A SECURITY GROUP THAT ALLOWS ALL OUTBOUND TRAFFIC or at least the traffic to the port your ALB listener is on.  Start by allowing all outbound traffic just to prove that is the problem then narrow it down.  This solved my 503 problem and hope it helps.

Comment: user19833168. This issue seems really struggling, I've tried your suggestion but it still 503...

Answer (score 3):

So I was using the AWS CDK 2.85.0 and I created an `HttpAlbIntegration` and just passed the (first) listener of the ALB of my Fargate service. For some reason AWS does create a VPC link for you, but that VPC link does not receive the appropriate `SecurityGroups`. Therefore the "out of the box" setup does not work. Manually creating a VPC link and adding that to the props of the `HttpAlbIntegration` did it for me:

```js
const securityGroup = new SecurityGroup(this, "allow-in", {
  vpc: myVpc,
  allowAllOutbound: true,
})
securityGroup.connections.allowFrom(ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(), ec2.Port.tcp(80))
securityGroup.connections.allowFrom(ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(), ec2.Port.tcp(443))

const vpcLink = new VpcLink(this, "link", {
  vpc: myVpc,
  subnets: {
    subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
  },
  securityGroups: [securityGroup]
})

const api = new HttpApi(this, "my-api", {})

const proxyIntegration = new HttpAlbIntegration('my-alb', myLoadBalancer.listeners[0], {
  vpcLink: vpcLink
})
api.addRoutes({
  path: "/myroute",
  methods: [HttpMethod.ANY],
  integration: proxyIntegration
})
```

(Please note, that this code is part of a larger setup and might not work independently)

Comment: Thank you this was driving me nuts.  Something must have recently changed in the last couple of versions of CDK because just a few months ago  I was able to get this to work without having to define the security group.

Comment: Thank you, this was very much the same issue for me. For those who are looking for a python equivalent of the solution, it's something like this gist below
https://gist.github.com/xgt001/d5c47c47c2f772c4db0ca67a138eb6b3

Answer (score 2):

For me, this was caused by having the default security group of the VPC with no outbound rules (and no inbound rules either, but that doesn't matter in this case). Without providing any security groups to the VpcLink, it was actually using the default one, which was blocking all outbound traffic from the VpcLink to my ALB.

I verified this was the case by temporarily adding an outbound rule to my default security group for all traffic and it started to work.

Thus, the solution I went with was to create a security group specifically for the VpcLink, with single outbound rule allowing traffic to the security group of my ALB.

Note I was using AWS CDK apigateway2-alpha, version 2.104.0a0